# Get element by classname inside certain div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to click some buttons in a page which has this html code

```
<div class="a">
  <span>
   <a class="b" role="button">test</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

So what i've tried is to take ONLY the div's class `a`

```
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('a').getElementsByClassName('b');

 for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++)  
     buttons[i].click();
```

Is there anyway to get the button with class name `b` but Only the one that is inside the div with class name `a` ??

P.S. i have also tried and this

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('a').getElementsByTagName('span').getElementsByClassName('b');

     for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++)  
         buttons[i].click();
```

But i get an empty array `[ ]` as a response when I `console.log(buttons)`

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)  is always useful.

Comment: `var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].getElementsByClassName('b');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use querySelector to overcome the issue.

> document.querySelectorAll("div.a a.b");

Comment: indeed. var set = document.querySelectorAll('.a .b'); for(var i=0; i<set.length; i++){ set[i].click(); }

Comment: @flowtron still i get an empty array as a response when i `console.log(set)`

Answer (score 0):

Since only one div will be assigned the `class='a'`, you can either supply an ID instead, or, you can do this :

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].getElementsByTagName('span');
// [0] indicates the first element with the class='a'
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)  {
    spans[i].getElementsByClassName('b')[0].click();
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <span>
    <a class="b" role="button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.log(this.innerHTML+' was clicked !')">test 1</a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a class="b" role="button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.log(this.innerHTML+' was clicked !')">test 2</a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a class="b" role="button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.log(this.innerHTML+' was clicked !')">test 3</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

This works perfectly, here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/nd8m7mms/4/

Comment: Nope its not clicking the button :/

Comment: (i < buttons.length) not (i <= buttons.length), and add the braces { ... }

Comment: I get an empty array `[ ]`as a response when i try to `console.log(buttons)`

Comment: i think the issue is with the `<span>` because when i try ONLY the certain button `classname = b` i get the results i want.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined` with your last edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and do

var buttons = $('.a > .b');

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XPath solution:

```js
let res = document.evaluate('//*[@class="a"]//*[@class="b"]',document,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
res.iterateNext().click();
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <span>
   <a class="b" role="button" onclick="console.log('clicked!')">test</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately [Internet Explorer still doesn't support the XPath API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Ok so your code works but only once. If i run it again through console of chrome i get this `Uncaught TypeError: Identifier 'res' has already been declared`

Comment: Sounds like you redeclared `res`. That's a mistake that has nothing to do with the XPath solution. Did you simply copy-and-paste the two lines of code? You can't say `let res` twice, that's a redeclaration.